# Best way to close connection in a class to simplify c# DB connections for SQL queries/updates

Tags: c#

I'm learning C#, and, have created a class to simplify what I have to do to execute an SQL query and loop through the results and also, to run an update. In both cases, pass the SQL and an optional list of parameters.

Here's the class that does the simplification:

```
    public db(string pQuerySQL, List<string> pParams=null) {
        //Params array replace @PARAM1, @PARAM2, @PARAM3 (etc) in the SQL
        //code would be: com.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@PARAM1", pParams[0]));
        con= new OleDbConnection(db.conString);
        com = con.CreateCommand();
        com.CommandText = pQuerySQL;
        addParamsToCom(lCom, pParams);
        con.Open();
        rs = com.ExecuteReader();
    }

    public static void runUpdate(string pUpdateSQL, List<string> pParams = null) {
        //Params array replace @PARAM1, @PARAM2, @PARAM3 (etc) in the SQL

        OleDbConnection lCon = new OleDbConnection(db.conString);
        OleDbCommand lCom = lCon.CreateCommand();
        lCom.CommandText=pUpdateSQL;
        addParamsToCom(lCom, pParams);
        lCon.Open();
        lCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        lCon.Close();
    }

    private static void addParamsToCom(OleDbCommand pCom,List<string> pParams = null) {
        if(!(pParams is null)) {    //Add params to the SQL
            for(int i = 0;i<pParams.Count;i++) {
                pCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PARAM"+(i+1).ToString(), pParams[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The advantage is that the class exposes the DataReader (recordset), so you can do db.rs.Read() or use any other functionality that it has.

Passing parameters is easy. Example with one parameter (to pass none, omit the 2nd parameter and just pass the SQL):

```
db db = new db(
    "SELECT trackTitle FROM tracks WHERE [band]=@PARAM1",
    new List<String> { "Sisters of Mercy" }
);
while (db.rs.Read()){
    Debug.WriteLine(db.rs["trackTitle"]);
}
db.close();
```

[20171027: Added code to deal with parameters]

How could I make the connection close-itself as the object is destroyed (i.e. after its scope collapses)?

Comment: This is probably better placed on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not SO given the style of your question.

Comment: Alos look at IDisposable, Finalizers etc

Comment: Perhaps you should start with an ADO.NET tutorial? Or any ASP.NET tutorial, almost all cover database access through Entity Framework. This class *doesn't* simplify access. In fact, it contains multiple bugs. You *don't* want to close the connection manually. Use a `using` block to ensure it's closed as soon as possible even if an exception occurs. As a consequence, the connection shouldn't be stored in a field. Dont' hard-code the connection string. Don't store the *reader* in a field, as it requires a connection

Comment: @tolanj maybe the first part of the question "is there anything I'm missing", but the second half "how could I make the connection close itself" is a valid one.  I suggest an edit to remove the code review bits to concentrate on the connection closing.

Comment: In fact, you should probaly check Dapper.NET for an example of an *actual* simplification.

Comment: Further, extremely serious bug: the query string itself. If you need to pass any parameters, you'll have to construct the query string by concatenating the values. This can easily expose your code to SQL injection and conversion issues. You should use parameterized queries with strongly typed parameters

Comment: Check out the [dispose pattern from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose).  You need to cleanup the resources that your db class creates in the disposal.

Comment: @robbymurphy that link won't help. The OP shouldn't even keep the connection and reader alive, much less wait for an external call to dispose them. The method that executes the command should open both and dispose them before even returning

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not saying that an external call should dispose it.  The `using(var myDb = new db())` pattern would guarantee dispose is called after the scope of the using block.

Comment: @robbymurphy the link you provided talks about adding IDisposable to a class. That's not what's needed here.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I'll get to them! You guys have said to read up on ADO.Net tutorials, Entity Framework, Dapper.NET, the dispose pattern, IDisposable... it'll take a while to get through all those.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - regarding simplification: the class DOES simplify access to the database, by at least 20 lines of code. Just instantiate "db" and you've got a recordset. Couldn't be simpler... except for me wanting the recordset to close itself once I'm done, which is my question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Regarding bugs: So far, I've used this for a few different SELECT queries, and I'm struggling to imagine what bugs could occur, excepting the case that you point out where an exception causes the app to close prematurely, before calling .close(). I am aware I haven't added any exception-handling yet (haven't looked up how to do it at all in C#!... later!).

You said I shouldn't store the connection in a field. I don't - it's stored in a private object in the DB class. I can't imagine how else it would be possible.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Regarding malicous SQL injection: As you say, if the calling function built plaintext SQL queries, a user could add data with long strings of SQL and get my poor app to do anything they want! I'm aware of this issue. I will create an optional parameter on the constructor class which accepts a list. If passed, it will take the list and add each one as a parameterized query. So - that'll be fixed as the class matures with additional use cases. I'll update the OP with the code once done (probably not today).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: So finally, regarding "The OP shouldn't even keep the connection and reader alive, much less wait for an external call to dispose them" - so, I should cache/store all the returned data rows, and return the cache? That way, it could cache the results and close the connection within the constructor. I'll give that a go!